# I want to use the .htacess to do 3 things

Tags: .htaccess

I want to use the .htacess to do 3 things

I can't get all 3 to work any help would be great.

1. Redirect http to https
2. Remove the trailing slash
3. I want people to be able to find my pages whether they use .html or not.

I'm currently using the code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.gasstudio.co.uk/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have your htaccess file in following way. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://www.gasstudio.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

##Html rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Screech, could you please do let me know if this solution has helped you? Thank you.